# notepad++ remove text between two string using regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to remove text between two strings using `regular expression` in **notepad++**. Here is my full string

```
[insertedOn]) VALUES (1, N'1F9ACCD2-3B60-49CF-830B-42B4C99F6072',
```

I want final string like this

```
[insertedOn]) VALUES (N'1F9ACCD2-3B60-49CF-830B-42B4C99F6072',
```

Here I removed **1,** from string. **1,2,3** is in incremental order.

I tried lot of expression but not worked. Here is one of them `(VALUES ()(?s)(.*)(, N')`

How can I remove this?

Comment: Try `(VALUES \().*?,\s*(N')` = > `$1$2`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this `(VALUES \().*?,\s*(N')` and it worked :)

Comment: I posted an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(VALUES \().*?,\s*(N')
```

and replace with `$1$2`. Note that in case the part of string to be removed can contain line breaks, enable the *`.` matches newline*. If the `N` and `VALUES` must be matched only when in ALLCAPS, make sure the *Match case* option is checked.

**Pattern details**

- `(VALUES \()` - Group 1 (later referred with `$1` from the replacement pattern): a literal substring `VALUES (`
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the leftmost occurrence of the sunsequent subpatterns
- `,\s*` - a comma and 0+ whitespaces (use `\h` instead of `\s` to only match horizontal whitespace chars)
- `(N')`  - Group 2 (later referred with `$2` from the replacement pattern): a literal substring  `N'`.

[image]

Comment: A relatively minor point but rather than using `.*?` it is better pactice to use `[^,]*`. It doesn't really matter for this particular string but when you have longer strings to match using the lazy quantifier is less efficient. It takes twice as many steps using lazy quantifier as it is checking each character twice in effect whereas using `[^,]` just matches until it gets to a `,`.

Comment: One more thing which is just a style choice is in one instance you use ` ` for whitespace after values and the other you use `\s`. It doesn't matter but I would choose one and stick with it. I prefer `\s` for readability.

Comment: @JackPRead I see, I also exdplained that `\h` can be more useful than `\s`.. `[^,]*` is a moot enhancement, because it will prevent a match if there is a `,` on the way from `VALUE (` to `N'`.

Comment: `.*?,` and `[^,]*,` match exactly the same thing except the former takes twice as many steps. Both will prevent a match if there is a `,` on way like you said. As I said above though for a string of this size the optimisation is negligible and both regex are valid for this string.

Comment: @JackPRead No, `[^,]*` cannot match the same way as `.*?` *here*, see [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/m908te/2) vs. [your variation](https://regex101.com/r/m908te/3). They are only working the same when there is a single atom on the right (e.g. `a.*?b` = `a[^b]*b`) In the OP scenario, the right hand boundary is a sequence of patterns, thus, `.*?` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You should first escape literal `(` before `VALUES`: `\(`

By doing so, `.*` in your regex in addition to `s` (DOTALL) flag causes engine to greedily match up to end of input string then backtracks to stop at the first occurrence of `, N'` which means unexpected matches.

To improve your regex you should 1) make `.*` ungreedy 2) remove `(?s)` 3) escape `(`:

```
(VALUES \().*?, (N')
```

To be more precise in matching you'd better search for:

```
VALUES \(\K\d+, *(?=N')
```

and replace with nothing.

Breakdown:

- `VALUES \(` March `VALUES (` literally
- `\K` Reset match
- `\d+, *` Match digits preceding a comma and optional spaces
- `(?=N')` Followed by `N'`

Comment: Thanks for reply :)